# getting started with smart gwt

Tags: autocomplete, combobox, module, smartgwt

I am developing a small scale app using smart gwt 2.4. I chose smart gwt over other html specific RIAs as it has rich ui and to avoid cross browser issues.
I have 2 pages in my app. Initially, the details that the user enters in page 1 is used to fetch data that has to be displayed in page 2 and from then on, any change that has to be made can be made in page 2 itself. the user needn't navigate back to page 1 to get a new set of data. 
1) Now, how do i navigate between pages. i have defined these pages as two separate modules. I wil need to pass data from page 1 to page 2. Is there an efficient way to do this?
2) In one of my pages i have defined two autocomplete combo boxes. data for one of the combo boxes will be fetched on load and the data for the second one depends on the value of the 1st combo box. I tried adding change and changed event listeners for the 1st combo box but both of the events are getting fired for every letter type. I need to fetch data once the user selects the value.

```
public void onModuleLoad() 
{ 
        final ComboBoxItem category = new ComboBoxItem("categoryName", "Category");  
        category.setTitle("Select");  
        category.setChangeOnKeypress(false) ;
        category.setType("comboBox");  
        category.setWidth(250);
        category.setIcons(icon);
        category.setChangeOnKeypress(false);
        final ComboBoxItem subCategory = new ComboBoxItem("subCategoryName", "Sub Category");  
        subCategory.setTitle("Select");  
        subCategory.setType("comboBox");  
        subCategory.setWidth(250);
        subCategory.addClickHandler(new com.smartgwt.client.widgets.form.fields.events.ClickHandler()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(com.smartgwt.client.widgets.form.fields.events.ClickEvent event) 
            {
                    // call to servlet[url] to get the sub categories for the selected category.
                    RequestBuilder requestBuilder = new RequestBuilder(RequestBuilder.GET, "url"+ selectedCategoryName);
                    try {
                        requestBuilder.sendRequest(null, new RequestCallback() {

                            @Override
                            public void onResponseReceived(Request request, Response response) 
                            {
                                   String xmlText = response.getText();
                                   // Code to handle the received response.
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onError(Request request, Throwable exception) 
                            {
                                exception.printStackTrace();

                            }});
                    } catch (RequestException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


            }
        });
        category.addChangeHandler(new ChangeHandler() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onChange(ChangeEvent event) 
            {
                if(null!=event.getValue() && event.getValue()!="")
                {
                    selectedCategoryName = event.getValue().toString();
                    System.out.println(selectedCategoryName);
                }
            }
        });
}
```

here i have a combo box category whose values will fetched on load. when the user selects a category by typing it in the combo box the control helps by displaying matched values in the drop down. for every key press, the event is getting is fired. i have added a syso to print the typed values. I need to fetch the sub category only when the user is done selecting the category.

Any pointers will be really useful.
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your second question: According to your need I think you can implement module as per this [link](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#dep_selectects_combobox_category).
OR if you want to implement it yourself by handling changed event, to stop firing change event on every key press you can use this:

```
comboBoxItem.setChangeOnKeypress(false);
```

Comment: I have implemented my combobox as per this [link](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#styled_combobox_category). My problem is the change event is getting fired for every key press. Assume i'm searching for CAT. It gets fired 3 times each for C, A and T. I need an event to notify the listener that I have selected CAT. Once I have the value CAT, I will fire another request to get the data based on CAT[the first value]. As of now its not happening that way.

Comment: Have you implemented comboBoxItem.setChangeOnKeypress(false);?

Comment: Can you post your code here in such a manner that I can also reproduce it?

Comment: Hey Karthik, I've tried your sample code. The `change event of comboboxItem` fires only when the `comboboxItem` loses its **focus**. It's not getting fired on every key press.

Comment: Oh is it? When I ran this code, the syso statement print every letter of my input. C, CA, CAT. I'll check. Thanks RAS

Comment: Your first question is might be answered at [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5949360/gwt-how-to-create-a-new-page.

Comment: @RAS- The link worked like charm for the first question. Thanks man. And on the second question, if I set the setChangeOnKeypress to false the drop down is not listing the matched values. i.e. the drop down is not opening up to display filtered values.