# GWT real world token usage

Tags: url, gwt, mvp, token

So it looks like when using GWT Activities & Places, a token is always required. My question is, what token would you provide for a page that would not typically have any additional arguments, such as a contact us page or place. Currently it looks like /#ContactUsPlace:token with a random token appended.

How do other developers use tokens.

Many thanks,
Alex

Comment: You need to show some code to clarify things. Did you start up an activityManager, PlaceHistoryHandler, and a PlaceController?

Comment: I've followed the MVP tutorial on the GWT homepage, http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideMvpActivitiesAndPlaces.html Then I just made the amendments Javier listed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [link] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5949360/gwt-how-to-create-a-new-page/5950019#5950019

Comment: Sorry, I seem to have made myself unclear. How does this fit in with the GWT Activities & Places, MVP framework? The current structure I'm using is fine, but when it comes to pages that should not typically have any appending token, I can't seem to remove it. I wanted to know what other developers do when using GWT Activities & Places MVP, when in the same situation as mentioned above (a contact us page). Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can return empty token which will change url to /#ContactUsPlace: 
Also you can change prefix using @Prefix annotation to get ex. /#contactus:

If you want more controll then you can implement your own PlaceHistoryMapper, here is a simple example:

```
public class KatPlaceHistoryMapper implements PlaceHistoryMapper{
    private static final String CONTACT = "contact";
    private static final String ABOUT_US = "aboutUs";

    @Override
    public Place getPlace(String hash) {
        if(token == null)
            return new DefaultPlace();
        else if(token.equals(CONTACT))
            return new ContactPlace();
        else if(token.equals(ABOUT_US))
            return new AboutUsPlace();
        else
            return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getToken(Place place) {
        if(place instanceof DefaultPlace)
            return ""
        else if(place instanceof ContactPlace)
            return CONTACT;
        else if(place instanceof AboutUsPlace)
            return ABOUT_US;
        else
            return null;
    }
}
```

Tokens returned/taken by above methods are actually whole hash-strings (not just the part after ':' ). In fact you get rid of tokens at all when using this approach.
Writing own generator which would generate this class at compile-time seems to be a good choice. Also don't use PlaceHistoryMapperWithFactory, it gives you the same what you get with PlaceTokenizers.

some docs: http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideMvpActivitiesAndPlaces.html#PlaceHistoryMapper