# Navigation in GWT

Tags: gwt, navigation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [GWT: How to create a new page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5949360/gwt-how-to-create-a-new-page)

I am working on GWT project and using Hyperlink for navigation, I am using AbsolutePanel and RootPanel.

On the click event of HyperLink I am clearing the content of RootPanel by using `RootPanel.remove(AbsolutePanel1) and RootPanel.clear();` and adding another AbsolutePanel to the RootPanel with different controls in the second AbsolutePanel. It is working fine when I click it once and use it, but after clicking the Hyperlink when the second AbsolutePanel is in the page when I refresh the page the AbsolutePanel1 is also displayed which I dont want as I have removed it from the RootPanel in the click event.

Please tell me any way from which it may work properly and the back button of browser is also not working.

Comment: Hey Amandeep, have you gone through this [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5949360/gwt-how-to-create-a-new-page/5950019#5950019)? Might be the answer you're searching for.

Comment: Hi,How I can accept any answer.I was not aware about it,please let me know details about it.Thanks

Comment: Go to your questions and click accept (check sign) on answers that you think best answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

Removing a elements in a gwt app only removes it in the current DOM, if you reload the page you also restart the gwt app and it does not "know" that it was run before and if any dom element were removed or not.