# GWT Page Navigation

Tags: gwt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [GWT: How to create a new page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5949360/gwt-how-to-create-a-new-page)

i'm new to GWT. I want to know, how to navigate from one page to another one?
In my application, in the home screen, after enter the username, password. If the username, password matches. A new page should open to display the contents. I'm using the MVP Architecture.

Answer (score 1):

In GWT application navigation is different from a classic webapp model. GWT is an asynchronous framework, you rather switch content of your page and manage the [History](http://code.google.com/intl/pl/webtoolkit/doc/1.6/DevGuideCodingBasics.html#DevGuideHistory) by built in tools rather that opening new webpages. Plese refer to Expenses sample located inside GWT SDK or try to use [Spring ROO](http://www.springsource.org/spring-roo) to scaffold your app using MVP.

Expenses in particular uses custom sliding panel to switch contents between for instance Details View and list view of all expenses.

If you really need to move to a new page, please see this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5949360/gwt-how-to-create-a-new-page).

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet is to study [Activities and Places](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideMvpActivitiesAndPlaces.html).  Work through the documentation and the examples.  When you figure it out, you'll realize that it gives you the page-to-page experience that a user expects from a website, including navigation via history, bookmarks, and the Back button, but in an MVP achitecture (also built into Activities and Places via the ActivityManager) and within a single actual page with GWT swapping in and out the contents (as per the answer from VoodoRider).